# Как исправить ошибку в преобразовании типов

Tags: c, указатели

Помогите исправить ошибку

```
 int  array[100];
 List * list = List_new();
 json_t * dataObj = json_object_get(jsonArr, "data");
  json_array_foreach(dataObj, index, value) {

      array[index] =json_integer_value(json_array_get(dataObj,index));
      List_add(list, array[index]);
 }
```

> note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
>    void List_add(List * self, void * ref);

Answer (score 2):

Что такое ваш `List`, увы, вы не показываете...

Но суть ошибки в том, что ваша функция `List_add` должна получать в качестве аргументов указатель на `List` и указатель `void*`, а вы ей передаете целое число - `array[index]`. Просто чтоб компилировалось, конечно, можно просто написать `List_add(list, (void*)array[index]);`, но вряд ли это то, что вам нужно. Без знания, что и как делает `List_add`, говорить о *правильном* решении не приходится.

Но, откровенно говоря, приведенный код вообще имеет очень странный вид, так что если эта ошибка единственная - я буду очень удивлен...